# Chrome rendering sizes as decimals, Firefox as integers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Chrome and Firefox, same page, same CSS, with `normalize.css`, render differently.

It started out as a select box being a few pixels short in Firefox. I've since traced it to two issues:

- Firefox renders responsive elements(`rem`', `em`) as integers. `80 in CSS is 2em on the page.
- Firefox renders borders differently than Chrome.

Is there a way to have render pages the same?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/), i think this would turn your pages run out of font rendering issues, and also try adding meta tag within `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

here are the other references i would like you to refer, if the problem persists 
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/